# How can I make a multiusers conference using webrtc

Tags: javascript, webrtc

Hi I have this code about video chat using webrtc,The original code was implementing peer to peer video call (two users only), now I want to make it possible for three users to talk (video and audio) but I don't know how to call two createAnswer() function for each peer variable after the createOffer(), it's not logical to do that! how should I do it? I am sorry if it was a duplicated question or a stupid one :) but I couldn't find any thing on the web, thanks

```
   function hasUserMedia() {
    navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || 
    navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || 
    navigator.msGetUserMedia;
    return !!navigator.getUserMedia;
    }
    function hasRTCPeerConnection() {
    window.RTCPeerConnection = window.RTCPeerConnection || 
    window.webkitRTCPeerConnection || window.mozRTCPeerConnection;
    return !!window.RTCPeerConnection;
    }
    var yourVideo = document.querySelector('#yours'),
    theirVideo = document.querySelector('#theirs'),
    theirVideo2 = document.querySelector('#theirs2'),
    yourConnection, theirConnection, theirConnection2;
    if (hasUserMedia()) {
    navigator.getUserMedia({video: true, audio: false}, function (stream) {
    yourVideo.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
        if (hasRTCPeerConnection()) {
            startPeerConnection(stream);
        } else {
            alert("Sorry, your browser does not support WebRTC.");
        }
    }, function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
} else {
    alert("Sorry, your browser does not support WebRTC.");
}
function startPeerConnection(stream) {
    var configuration = {
        "iceServers": [{"url": "stun:127.0.0.1:9876"}]
    };
    yourConnection = new webkitRTCPeerConnection(configuration);
    theirConnection = new webkitRTCPeerConnection(configuration);
    theirConnection2 = new webkitRTCPeerConnection(configuration)
    // Setup stream listening
    yourConnection.addStream(stream);
    theirConnection.onaddstream = function (e) {
        theirVideo.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(e.stream);
    };
    theirConnection2.onaddstream = function (e) {
        theirVideo2.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(e.stream);
    }
    // Setup ice handling
    yourConnection.onicecandidate = function (event) {
        if (event.candidate) {
            theirConnection.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(event.candidate));
        }
    };
    theirConnection2.onicecandidate = function (event) {
        if (event.candidate) {
            yourConnection.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(event.candidate));
        }
    };

    theirConnection.onicecandidate = function (event) {
        if (event.candidate) {
            yourConnection.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(event.candidate));
        }
    };
    // Begin the offer
    yourConnection.createOffer(function (offer) {
        yourConnection.setLocalDescription(offer);
        theirConnection.setRemoteDescription(offer);
        theirConnection2.setRemoteDescription(offer);

        theirConnection.createAnswer(function (offer) {
            theirConnection.setLocalDescription(offer);
            // theirConnection2.setRemoteDescription(offer);
            yourConnection.setRemoteDescription(offer);
        }, function (err) {
            console.log(err)
        });
        theirConnection2.createAnswer(function (offer) {
            theirConnection2.setLocalDescription(offer);
            // theirConnection.setRemoteDescription(offer);
            // yourConnection.setRemoteDescription(offer);
        }, function (err) {
            console.log(err)
        });
    }, function (err) {
        console.log(err)
    });
};
```

Comment: We are not a code writing service, you should have a clear question and a problem. Please review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I am sorry for not making my question clear, I don't want from you to write code for me I just want  to know how can I connect more than two users into a video chat, I mean by that make a video conference between multiple users using webrtc.

Comment: @OmarShrbaji I think it is very tough to make a purely peer-to-peer multiuser conference. I was able to achieve such a feature using a centralized model, with a WebRTC Media Server inbetween. Check out Kurento, this example in particular: http://doc-kurento.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorials.html#webrtc-many-to-many-video-call-group-call

Comment: @FreemanLambda Tahnks a lot for your answer , I had a look on kurento and I will give it a try, however I found my answer on [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33601949/webrtc-videoconferencing-many-to-many?rq=1) with a great example on github

Comment: This is great! I had the same approach, just wrapped with kurento client side helpers. Consider marking the question as a duplicate of the one in the link please.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WebRTC videoconferencing (many-to-many)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33601949/webrtc-videoconferencing-many-to-many)